# how to install pgmpy on anaconda 3 using the anaconda prompt

Tags: python, installation, prompt, anaconda3, pgmpy

the following errors pop us while trying to install pgmpy

```
(base) C:\Users\pc> conda install -c ankurankan pgmpy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abor\
Examining pgmpy:  50%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████                                                                               | 1/2 [00:00<00:00,  4.40it/s]-failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
pip install pgmpy
```